# PrimeFaces 3.5 with WebSphere 6.1

Tags: jsf, primefaces, websphere-6.1

I have a problem with WebSphere 6.1 and Primefaces. I have created an application, but used a local Tomcat appserver for testing. Everything was working fine, until I tried to deploy it on WAS 6.1.

After investigating the internal server problem, I saw, that WAS 6.1 only supports JSF 1.1, so I can throw out the whole interface :S

My question is, what is the best and most importantly, the fastest solution for this:

- my interface is very simple, only panels, commandbuttons, a menu and a printer component. Is it possible to go back to a previous version of primefaces that supports jsf 1.1 keeping most of the code? (as I read, primefaces 1.1 is the last, which is far away from 3.5 )
- use another faces implementation, if yes which one is the easiest to switch to from primefaces
- can WAS 6.1 be made somehow compatible with JSF 2?
- any other way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible if you drop the necessary JSF 2.0/2.1 + PrimeFaces 3.5 JARs in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` and set in WebSphere admin the classloader policy to `PARENT_LAST` on both the EAR and WAR. This will force WebSphere to load webapp-bundled JSF instead of its own bundled JSF.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately its not working. :( I also tried copying these jars into Websphere's lib directory, but with no luck either.

Comment: Don't touch Websphere's `/lib` directory. If it doesn't work, then the classloader policy isn't set right.

Comment: Thank you! Now it loads the jsf classes, but I got a new error :P

WebApp        E   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder (Caused by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder)
[2013.09.06. 20:28:02:436 GMT] 00000029 faces         E   Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory. Attempting to find backup. I tried adding the  <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>, but it did not help. Any idea?

Comment: i will create a new question for this, with more details, thank you for your help :)